# How start a Task and define a timeout to finish it

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, task, task-parallel-library

We have a project where we run some tasks in parallel. We are starting Tasks to do this. Every Task runs a code inside a `CodeDom` (written by customer to customize part of the process). It works fine.

I would like to know how to limitate the time of the execution of a Task. I am afraid of the user write a bad code and it result in something like infinity loop or a bad code which takes a lot of time to perform. I would like to give him 10 seconds to perform its code and after that, kill the thread that is running on the Task and finish the Task.

For sample (pseudo code):

```
Task[] tasks = GetListOfTasks();

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    task.Start();
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
Task.WaitAll(tasks, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I already have the cancelation token on all these tasks, but the user can't use it.

How can I stop the task execution and kill the tasks if it do not finish on the specified `TimeSpan` ?

Thank you.

```
var threadTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // start thread
    thread.Start();

    // force to wait the thread 
    thread.Join();
});

// run a new task to wait the task/thread to finish in a timeout.
// on the continueWith, abort the thread.
Task.Run(() => Task.WaitAll(new[] { threadTask }, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        if (thread.IsAlive)
        {
            thread.Abort();
        }
    });
```

Comment: As rory indicated, task cancellation is co-operative.

Comment: "Every Task start a new process" you mean real OS process, via Process.Start?

Comment: @Evk sorry, I've fix it. And no, it does not perform a `Process.Start`. The task runs retrieve a C# code from DataBase (defined by the user), compile and run it using CodeDom. I'm afraid to get a lot of time to execute it or a bad code (infinite loops). That's why I want to stop and kill the task based on a timeout.

Comment: Well I believe there is no good solution to this. Best you can do is start new thread for each operation and then call `Thread.Abort` after timeout. Hopefully you are running that compiled code in separate app domain, so aborting that thread (and tearing down app domain) should not have bad consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Evk. I understand the point to call Thread.Abort. I already have an some async tasks running (and each one perform a codedom independently) what you mean is to start a new `thread` to run the codeDom scope on this task? I ask it because I'm not sure because I am new on Parallelism/Tasks haha (sorry :D) (see my edit on question)

Comment: I mean just don't use tasks at all - use threads (like you do). If you want to work with task for convenience - at least use `TaskCompletionSource` instead of `Task.Run` in this case.