# Assert an infinite loop not to finish within seconds

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

As a software test engineer, I'm asking my software development engineer to write an infinite loop for me.

Let's the function my fellow will write is `canHalt(p)`. I've figured up a special state `p` that can make his `canHalt()` run forever. So it's high time to test it.

We use C# (.net core 3.1) with xunit.

What I have so far is

```
[Fact]
public async void RunInfiniteLoop()
{
    Turing p = ...

    // This configuration throws the solver into infinite loop.
    // Within 3 seconds, it will not finish.
    var task = Task.Run(() => Solver.canHalt(p));
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(3000));
    Assert.NotSame(task, completedTask);
}
```

So far so good, but the dummy SDE uses Console.Write within his canHalt function, and the output thus floods my screen.  I then wrap the whole thing with

```
var back = Console.Out;
Console.SetOut(System.IO.TextWriter.Null)
...

Console.SetOut(back);
```

It does the trick for this method only. But when I run `dotnet test  --verbosity normal`, which runs all tests in the solution, my screen is flooded again.

I gather it is because of `Console.SetOut(back)`. After RunInfiniteLoop() finishes execution, the canHalt() process isn't aborted, so it can continue writing to std.

I learned from [How start a Task and define a timeout to finish it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50291467/746461) Task is cooperative or we pass in a CancellationToken, but our specs says canHalt only accepts a state p; I can't squeeze in a token for testing purpose.

I guess it's better to abort the infinite function as the end of my test.

How would I do that?

Comment: If the method has no way to abort it you are left with dirty tricks like Thread.Abort which you really want to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good practice to write software components that lifespan can not be controlled. So specify to your fellow engineer that the method should accept and wire in a [CancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0) instance or some other means of ending the infinite loop on demand, and return some kind of state for vertifying that the method has terminated before the test method does. A custom [IAsyncResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncresult?view=net-7.0) - derived class instance or a Task instance would serve such a purpose.